# Can we find, in windows log file, rong password?

Tags: windows, security, authentication

I filled my password instead of my username in my work computer. I'd like to know if other persons (administrator) can see it in log files.
If so how can I delete it?

Second question: is it possible get list of all failed login attempts (wrong passwords).

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably safer to just change your password.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. Voting to close and move to [su] where it's more appropriate. The [faq] and [about] pages have more information about the types of questions that should be asked here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the answer for windows is less than congruent across versions, specificity with regards to that aspect would be appreciated.

For windows 7 I would refer you [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/monitor-attempts-to-access-and-change-settings-on-your-computer).

Prior to XP the windows "Event Log" would provide you with information that I believe would satiate your curiosity. However in XP+ things have changed. The XP version of the link I posted before is located [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310399&Product=winxp).

EDIT: For those who would like to do the same on linux...

On linux it's a bit simpler:
`faillog -u root` | Will list all failed root login attempts.

Whereas: `faillog -a` |
Will list failed login attempts for ALL system accounts.
The faillog file is located at `/var/log/faillog` & `>|/var/log/faillog` should wipe that file if that's what you're looking to do.

More information on faillog can be found here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/faillog

Comment: The "in windows log file" in the title and the `windows` tag should have made it clear this wasn't a Linux question, I'd think. :-)

Comment: Haha woops. Forgot about the title x). *COUGH* WELL THEN. edited accordingly.